# VLAN and Switch Recommendation

Tags: switch, vlan

We are in the process of installing a 20 Meg Metro-E connection and we need to be able to segment the bandwidth into 3 different VLAN's that should be completely separate for security reasons and be able to assign a max bandwidth usage rate per each VLAN.

First of all is this possible using 1 managed switch and would this be the recommended way to do it?

If yes, what is a good switch for this purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly you can do this using any QoS/CoS-capable switch but I'd advise you not to assign maximum bandwidth parameters to your segments but minimum ones, the reason I say this is why limit the second and third segments bandwidth if/when the first segment isn't busy and vice versa, what you want to do is protect what needs protecting and let everything else be done under 'best efforts'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the minimum bandwidth.  That makes more sense.

Comment: How would the VLAN's on non-routable subnets (192.x, etc.) get internet access?  Do you setup a gateway on the switch similar to the way you set it up on a router?

Comment: NAT usually....